# Find the largest divisor of an integer $b$.

Tags: calculus, number-theory, algorithms, binary, big-numbers

I want to find out an efficient method to calculate the largest divisor of a very big integer $b$ which can be up to $\large 2^{1000}$. That is, I want to find out an integer $a < b$, such that $a\mid b$ and a is the largest divisor. What's more, all integers, including the answer a, are in their binary representations. Thanks in advance.

Example:$ b = 101, a = 1$; $b = 110, a = 11.$

Comment: Finding the largest divisor $<b$ is equivalent to finding the smallest divisor $d>1$ and computing $a=\frac bd$

Comment: Find the smallest divisor $c$ such that $b>c>1$, then largest divisor would be $a=\dfrac{b}{c}$

Comment: No one knows an efficient method guaranteed to find *any* non-trivial divisor of a 300-digit number, much less the largest (or smallest). Lower your sights: what will you settle for?

Answer (score 3):

In theory, if you can find the smallest divisor and make the division this should give the largest divisor though this is basically running through a list of the smallest primes.  For example, if $ 2 | b $ then the largest divisor will be $b/2$ as there isn't anything larger that would divide $b$ as there aren't any integer factors less than $2$ and greater than $1$.  Thus, the challenge is to do a series of divisions though this is a bit of a brute force approach.